# How to set all formik values at once?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a `formik` form for editing data which comes from an API endpoint,currently I am re-initializing the values in a `useEffect` hook like this

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    initialValues.first_name = address?.first_name;
    initialValues.last_name = address?.last_name;
    initialValues.middle_name = address?.middle_name;
    initialValues.label = address?.label;
    initialValues.description = address?.description;
  }, [address, initialValues]);
```

since the form has many values the `useEffect` hook gets lengthy and does not look clean either, I am trying to find a way to do it in a single line so it does not get a giant piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so it worked when I used formik.setValues, since it returns a promise so I put it in an asynchronous function. [formik.setValues](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setvalues-fields-reactsetstateaction-field-string-any--shouldvalidate-boolean--void)

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function setInitialValues() {
      if (address) await formik.setValues(address, false);
    }
    setInitialValues();

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [address]);
```

Comment: Another possibility could be when you pass initalValues to Formik component use `initalValues = {valuesFromAPI || initialValues}` where `valuesFromAPI` is object containing data from api. And add `enableReinitialize` prop to formik component. You can refer this tutorial `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awCY7qnbkIA`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding setValues prop by passing object as argument.

Solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
     formik.setValues({
        first_name: address?.first_name,
        last_name: address?.last_name,
        middle_name: address?.middle_name,
        label: address?.label,
        description: address?.description
      });
  }, ["ADD YOUR DEPENDENCY"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It‘s my idea of this question ,you can use the [pick](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick) from `ramda`,and when the fromfield add new column you just need to push the label to the `formDataLabels`, I hope it may work for you.

```js
import {pick} from 'ramda';

// ... 

React.useEffect(() => {
    const formDataLabels = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name', 'label', 'description'];
    const updateData = pick(formDataLabels, address);
    initialValues = {
        ...initialValues,
        ...updateData,
    };
}, [address, initialValues]);
```