# React Native Element Dropdown, Passing Dropdown selected value to parent component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-picker

I'm attempting to pass the value selected from the child component dropdown picker to the parent component and store it into formik. but I cant seem to figure it out.

Github react-native-element-dropdown package used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown

Parent Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import StyledPicker from "../Inputs/StyledPicker";

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
        <View>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{     
              kgLb: "",
            }}
            onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
              if (values.kgLb == "") {
                setMessage("Please fill in fields to procced.");
                setSubmitting(false);
              } else {}
            }}
          >
            {({
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit,
              values,
              isSubmitting,
            }) => (
                    <StyledPicker
                      label="Enter Kg Or Lb:"
                      icon="fitness-center"              
                      keyboardType="default"
                      onChangeText={handleChange("kgLb")}
                      onBlur={handleBlur("kgLb")}
                      value={values.kgLb}
                    />
                )
            }

               {!isSubmitting && (
                  <RegularButton
                    style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}
                    onPress={handleSubmit}
                  >
                    {buttonText || `Complete`}
                  </RegularButton>
                )}
                {isSubmitting && (
                  <RegularButton style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="primary" />
                  </RegularButton>
                )}
          </Formik>
        </View>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Child Component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { Dropdown } from "react-native-element-dropdown";

const data = [
  { label: "KG", value: "KG" },
  { label: "LB", value: "LB" },
];

const StyledPicker = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
  console.log(value);

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Picker/Dropdown isn't submiting the value to the parent component */}
          <Dropdown
            {...props}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            data={data}
            search
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            placeholder={!isFocus ? "Example: Kg - Lb" : "..."}
            searchPlaceholder="Search..."
            value={value}
            onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
            onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
            onChange={(item) => {
              setValue(item.value);
              setIsFocus(false);
            }}
          />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default StyledPicker;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Make style picker receive an onChange function in the props!

In the child:

```js
onChange={(item) => {
   setValue(item.value);
   setIsFocus(false);
   props.onChange(item)
}}
```

in the parent:

```
// set a use state with the dropdown value
const [dropdownValue, setDropdownValue] = useState()

    //...
    <
    Formik
initialValues = {
    {
        kgLb: "",
    }
}
onSubmit = {
        (values, {
            setSubmitting
        }) => {
            if (values.kgLb == "") {
                setMessage("Please fill in fields to procced.");
                // here you can do something with dropdown value
                setSubmitting(false);
            } else {}
        }
    } >

    //...

    <
    StyledPicker
label = "Enter Kg Or Lb:"
icon = "fitness-center"
keyboardType = "default"
onChangeText = {
    handleChange("kgLb")
}
onBlur = {
    handleBlur("kgLb")
}
value = {
    values.kgLb
}
onChange = {
    setDropdownValue
}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks the value is now stored within the useState in my parent component. But formik isn't registering the value, How would I go about putting the useState value into value = { values.kgLb}

Comment: I've put the useState value within the formik initialValues={{ kgLb: dropdownValue.value }} but if I console.log(values.KgLb) it will give me back undefined value Object { "kgLb": undefined }

Comment: That is because initial values doesn't change after the first time initializing the component. See that formik has a prop called "setValues" perhaps that code = {{ kgLb: dropdownValue.value }} belongs there

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078332/how-to-set-all-formik-values-at-once he sets the values every time address changes. You would need to do the same but with dropdown value.